# Sending and receiving data in json using spring

Tags: json, spring

I am using POST MAN CLIENT of GOOGLE CHROME TO SEND articleName and articleId AS HEADER  application/json.What things I needed to change in my controller and library as well as in my spring servlet.xml?My controller is as follows.

public class ArticleController {

```
    @Autowired
    private ArticleService articleService;

    Article article = new Article();
    Long articleId = article.getArticleId();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public Article saveArticle(@ModelAttribute Article article,
            BindingResult bindingresult) {

        int a = articleService.addArticle(article);
        if (a == 1) {
            return new ModelAndView("success");
        } else {
            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }
    }


My Spring servlet is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.roseindia" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>






    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>net.roseindia.model.Article</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Plz help me out....Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want is to return JSON easily from Spring.

To do that you need Jackson dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

When you have it,
you can annotate your method with `@ResponseBody` annotation just like this:

```
public @ResponseBody Article saveArticle(@ModelAttribute Article article,
        BindingResult bindingresult) {
....
}
```

Such a method will return JSONified Article object in response.

Comment: But My project is not a MVC project but rather a dynamic web project so unable add the dependencies as I don't hava pom.xml here.

Comment: So just add it in a standard way, by attaching jar with Jackson.

Comment: But I have added the jackson mapper-asl-1.9.0 in build path as well as lib.But exception that is coming:org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter]:

Comment: So sorry, but I think there is a lot more to do, and it's not a matter of comment in StackOverflow. My advice is consider to move to Maven because handling dependencies with Maven is a lot easier than using manual configuration. Nevertheless I think you do use MVC since you use `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: After adding the jackson mapper what needs to be changed in spring-servlet.xml?

Comment: Add Jackson mapper asl & core jars in class path. And create jacksonmapper bean in context file whose one property accepts a package which contains beans to be jsonified.

Comment: Changed my project to a spring mvc project.Just added jackson dependency and found solution.Previously I was doing a Dynamic web project.Now added Requestbody and Responsebody annotations   to send and recieve data in json format.